# Convert string to UTF-8

Tags: vbscript

I have a string assigned to variable that's encoded as ansi, for example `str = "Пирг"`
How can I encode it to UTF-8?

Comment: See also [this newer question](/q/28834528/1178314).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean when writing it to a file? Like this:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type     = 2 'text
stream.Position = 0
stream.Charset  = "utf-8"
stream.WriteText str
stream.SaveToFile filename, 2
stream.Close
```

**Edit:** If you want the UTF-8 string to go into another variable you could do it like this:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type     = 2 'text
stream.Position = 0
stream.Charset  = "utf-8"
stream.WriteText str
stream.Flush
stream.Position = 0
stream.Type     = 1 'binary
stream.Read(3)      'skip BOM
utfStr = stream.Read
stream.Close
```

Comment: No I don't want to write to file. I'm passing this variable to URL to server which accept only utf-8 encoded strings. For example if I urlencode the string, or use `Escape()` function, server returns false status.